# Calculating limits using L'Hospital Rule

Tags: limits

> Calculate $$\ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(\ln x)^{25}}{x} $$ using L'Hospital Rule

My working is

$$\ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(\ln x)^{25}}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}(\ln x)^{25}}{\frac{d}{dx}x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{25(\ln x)^{24}}{x}=\dots=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{25!}{x}=0  $$

Is my working correct?

Moreover, wolfram alpha stated that **Since $\ln^{25} x $ grows asymptotically slower than the polynomial $x$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$, the limit is $0$.**

How can we possibly deduce that?

Edit: Third question

Will my working work if the power was $x$?

$$\ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(\ln x)^{x}}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}(\ln x)^{x}}{\frac{d}{dx}x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x(\ln x)^{x-1}}{x}=\dots=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x!}{x}=\infty  $$

Is this correct? The reason I am asking is because if $x\rightarrow \infty$ then the second last expression should never arise.

Comment: Where do your equalities come from?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos L'Hospital's rule...

Comment: It seems correct. Well you can easily say that $\frac{(\ln x)^n}x$ goes to $0$ by applying $n$ times the lhospital like you did.

Comment: i think it is correct

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I had the impression that the idea was *not* to use that rule. My mistake.

Comment: Can somebody answer the second question on the post?

Comment: The natural logarithm grows slower than $x$ does, so the fraction will approach zero since the denominator dominates. That's what wolfram is saying, but the argument with L'Hopital's rule is more rigorous.

Comment: @wgrenard Yes but there's also a power on the natural log? Shouldn't that complicate the assertation?

Comment: As per the edit, note that:$$\frac d{dx}(\ln(x))^x\ne x(\ln(x))^{x-1}$$Instead, we have:$$(\ln(x))^x=e^{(\ln(x))^2}\stackrel{\frac d{dx}}\implies\frac2x\ln(x)e^{\ln(x))^2}$$

Comment: @FaiqRaees That is exactly the opposite of what I wrote.  Reread the 'equal sign' carefully.

Comment: Oh okay got it.

Comment: Wait can you tell me how x becomes 2 in the following expression $(\ln(x))^x=e^{(\ln(x))^2}$?

Comment: Assuming the limit exists, we have, after apply L'H, $$L=L\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2\ln(x)}x=0\implies L=0$$ Of course, it needn't be the case that the limit exists at all... one would need to check that.

Comment: Note that: $a^b=(e^{\ln(a)})^b=e^{b\ln(a)}$

Comment: Yes but b= x not 2. Right?

Comment: Oh, whoops, I did make a mistake, my bad.  It should be
$$(\ln(x))^x=e^{x\ln(\ln(x))}\gg e^x\implies\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x}x=\infty$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\ln(t)}t=0$$

Then let $x=t^{25}$ in your limit to reduce it to

$$\begin{align}L&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{[\ln(x)]^{25}}x\\&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{[\ln(t^{25})]^{25}}{t^{25}}\\&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{[25\ln(t)]^{25}}{t^{25}}\\&=\left[25\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\ln(t)}t\right]^{25}\\&=0\end{align}$$

This quickly shows that for any $n$, we have

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{[\ln(x)]^n}x=0$$

Comment: Can you please see the edit?

Answer (score 2):

The general result is the following ( and is known in high school):

> Let $\alpha,\beta\,$ be positive real numbers. Then
>   $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\ln x)^\alpha}{x^\beta}=0.$$

To prove this assertion, it is enough to show the log of the fraction tends to $-\infty$. Now
$$\ln\frac{(\ln x)^\alpha}{x^\beta}=\alpha\ln(\ln x)-\beta \ln x=-\beta \ln x\biggl(1-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\frac{\ln(\ln x)}{\ln x}\biggr)$$
and setting $u=\ln x$, we see that
$$\frac{\ln(\ln x)}{\ln x}=\frac{\ln u}{u}\to 0\quad\text{when}\; x,\;\text{hence}\; u\to\infty,$$
so the content of the parenthesis tends to $1$, and the  log of the fraction tends to $-\infty$, like $-\beta\ln x$.